# What are the differences between final class and sealed class in Scala?

Tags: scala, access-modifiers

There are two types of modifiers in Scala: `final` and `sealed`

What are the differences between them? When should you use one over the other?

Answer (score 110, accepted):

A `final` class cannot be extended, period.

A `sealed` trait can only be extended in the same *source file* as it's declared. This is useful for creating ADTs (algebraic data types). An ADT is defined by the *sum* of its derived types.

E.g.:

- An `Option[A]` is defined by `Some[A]` + `None`.
- A `List[A]` is defined by `::` + `Nil`.

---

```
sealed trait Option[+A]

final case class Some[+A] extends Option[A]
object None extends Option[Nothing]
```

Because `Option[A]` is sealed, it cannot be extended by other developers - doing so would alter its *meaning*.

`Some[A]` is final because it cannot be extended, period.

---

As an added bonus, if a trait is sealed, the compiler can warn you if your pattern matches are not exhaustive enough because it *knows* that `Option` is *limited* to `Some` and `None`.

```
opt match {
    case Some(a) => "hello"
}
```

> Warning: match may not be exhaustive. It would fail on the following input: `None`

Comment: Technically speaking `sealed` templates can be extended in the same *compilation unit*, not the same file. The fact that the Scala compiler's compilation unit equals a file is an implementation detail. There could be other compilers which use, for example, a database to store source artifacts instead of the filesystem.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Thanks for the addendum, I wasn't aware of that distinction.

Answer (score 9):

`sealed` classes (or traits) can still be inherited in the same source file (where `final` classes can't be inherited at all).

Use `sealed` when you want to restrict the number of subclasses of a base class (see "Algebraic Data Type").

As one of the very practical benefits of such a restriction the compiler can now warn you about non-exaustive pattern matches:

```
sealed trait Duo
case class One(i:Int) extends Duo
case class Two(i:Int, j:Int) extends Duo

def test(d:Duo) {
  match {
    case One(x) => println(x) // warning since you are not matching Two
  }
}
```

Comment: Technically speaking `sealed` templates can be extended in the same *compilation unit*, not the same file. The fact that the Scala compiler's compilation unit equals a file is an implementation detail. There could be other compilers which use, for example, a database to store source artifacts instead of the filesystem.