# Difference between sealed and final class in Java

Tags: java, sealed-class, java-15

I have just read that Java 15 should have `sealed` classes.
[jep360](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/360) says:

> Sealed classes and interfaces restrict which other classes or interfaces may extend or implement them.

I thought that this is exactly what a `final class` does in Java.
So now I wonder: What is the difference between a `final class` and a `sealed class`?

Comment: Related: [what does non-sealed mean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63972130/what-is-the-difference-between-a-final-and-a-non-sealed-class-in-java-15s-seale) and [a question on the identically-named feature in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32199989/what-are-the-differences-between-final-class-and-sealed-class-in-scala/32200128).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`final class A {...}` means that no class is allowed extend `A`.

`sealed class A permits B {...}` means that only `B` can extend `A` but no other class is allowed to do that.